# How can I move the entire git repository somewhere else?

Tags: git

We have bunch of repositories on GitHub and we want to switch entirely to another provider. I'm a Mercurial fan so I'm not really familiar with Git branches and unfortunatelly when cloning a git repository you have to specify a branch otherwise it will clone the master one (if I'm not completely wrong here).

To be more specific with an example, let's assume that we have a project called `hello` that has a few branches (`master`, `a`, `b`). I would like to move that and then continue working in the new repository, by deleting the original one.

So we have this repository:

```
git@github.com:lipis/hello.git
```

And we want to move it to:

```
ssh://lipis@lipis.kilnhg.com/lipis/hello
```

Since we have more than 40 different projects and many of them have different branches my question is how could I move each of these repositories entirely (with all the branches) to another repository without pulling and pushing individual branches per project?

---

Would be nice to have some kind of procedure like:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:lipis/hello.git
$ cd hello
# some black git magic that only Linus understands..
# continue working with the newest repository only
```

Comment: The provider that you are switching to ought to have instructions for just this case - given that GitHub will be their competitor and they'll get this question frequently.

Comment: @GoZoner I disagree, stuff like this is not specific at all to GitHub. Perhaps conversion from another site in general, but not just for GitHub.

Comment: @GoZoner while you might be right.. I wanted to know how could I do that on my own.. because with mercurial you can do that simply by adding one line in the `hgrc` or just pushing to any url and you have it all.. but not using git :(

Comment: @Lipis Its really simple with git, its just a clone/push. I'm not sure why you are adding complexity to the situation. I have a feeling you don't understand how git works on a fundamental level. Try reading "Git from the bottom up"

Comment: @alternative Your answer is more or less complete.. I will just experiment tomorrow.. but with a simple clone/push I'm not seeing any branches in the new repo.. or maybe I'm totally missed something ;) We'll see tomorrow.. thanks

Comment: @Lipis Thats because when you clone, it doesn't create tracking branches for all of the remote branches. The commits and refs are there, you just have to name them yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git clone` does not clone a specific branch, it clones all of them and then checks out master.

The easiest way to do this is to simply push the repository to the new location with `--mirror`. You could also clone from the other side. You could also just copy the folder.

To elaborate on how `git clone` works, suppose we clone from a repository `origin` that has branches `master`, `a`, and `b`. Then in the new repository we get the branches `master`, `origin/master`, `origin/a`, and `origin/b`, and we can branch like `git branch a origin/a` to get our own copy of `a` in that new repository.

It might be difficult to push from the `github` repository so you should probably just use `git clone --mirror` (which sets up all the refs for us automatically). This is assuming that you have full access to your `ssh` server. If not, you should `git clone --mirror` from a 3rd machine and then `git push --mirror` to the `ssh` server.

Comment: I have full ssh access to all repositories and I simply wan to move them over Kiln. So to be more specific if we have this hello project and nothing on my machine.. what are the exact steps from cloning it to pushing it..? Thank you for the theory but is still confusing.. since I want to somehow automate this thing for 40 projects.. would be nice to have a procedure :)

Comment: @Lipis `git clone --mirror <initial url>` then `git push --mirror <new url>`. The reason for `--mirror` is that it ensures that all the refs are preserved. You'll then want to reconfigure your `origin` remote to point to the new repository in Kiln.

Comment: When I do the `git clone --mirror` it create a `hello.git` directory that contains only the git related files and not the project it self.. am I missing something?

Comment: @Lipis no, you are not missing anything: a `git clone --mirror` is always a *bare* repo (i.e. without working tree). See https://exyr.org/2011/git-mirrors/ as an example.

Comment: @Lipis Once you push to Kiln you can just clone either the local one and setup new remotes or you can clone the new remote one (both without using `--mirror`). `--mirror` is purely because we want the new remote to be a mirror of the old remote. The local mirror was only meant to be temporary, anyway.